# Issues with list manager (Python)?

Tags: python

I am having an issue with the output of this function:

```
def cmd_prompt():
print(input('Enter a command (? for help): '))
if str(input) == '?':
    print("*** Available Commands ***")
    label_spacing = 10
    num_spacing = 10
    print(pad_right('Add', label_spacing), pad_left('Add to list', num_spacing))
    print(pad_right('Delete', label_spacing), pad_left('Delete information', num_spacing))
    print(pad_right('List', label_spacing), pad_left('List information', num_spacing))
    print(pad_right('Clear', label_spacing), pad_left('Clear list', num_spacing))
    print('Empty to exit')
```

When I attempt to run it, the result is this:

```
cmd_prompt()
Enter a command (? for help): ?
?
```

How can I fix this and get it to run the specified output?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. For questions seeking debugging help, you must provide a [mcve]. This is way too much code to demonstrate your issue. In any case, the error message is quite clear. You are using `break` outside a loop. That is not valid syntax

Comment: It's probably because you're checking if the value of the _second_ `input()` call is equal to `?`, not the _first_ `input()`. `input()` allows for a string to be specified which will be the prompt next to the input that the user types in, so the `print()` call outside of the `input()` will print the result of what the user types in.

Comment: The second input isn't being called, and that's not how return values work.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line of code, you are asking for input twice. No need to ask input in if statement.

```
def cmd_prompt():
    i=input('Enter a command (? for help): ')
    if i == '?':
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> print(input('Enter a command (? for help): '))
> ```

You don't need to call `print` here. The `input` function will print whatever string you pass it. And then it will return the value entered by the user. You can then store that input value into a variable (ex. `command`) as a string. That is what you use for comparing to `?`.

Read the Python docs on [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> If the *prompt* argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that.

```
>>> def cmd_prompt():
...   command = input('Enter a command (? for help): ')
...   if command == '?':
...     print("*** Available Commands ***")
...     print("aaa")
...     print("bbb")
... 
>>> cmd_prompt()
Enter a command (? for help): ?
*** Available Commands ***
aaa
bbb
```